# How to remove static array after uncheck checkbox in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have two checkboxes, and I want whenever I click on any checkbox then their values (static array) should be inserted into "final" array (empty array). If I uncheck that checkbox then its value (static array) should be remove from "final array".

Right now I am inserting/pushing "static" array into blank array (final array), but I want to know that how can I remove this "static" array after uncheck checkbox ?

```js
var myarray = [];
var model = ["Height", "size", "bust"];
var Hostess = ["Height", "bust"];

$("input:checkbox.country").click(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (!$(this).is(":checked"))
    alert('you are unchecked ' + $(this).val());

  else
    myarray.push(model);
});
console.log('Final array is ', myarray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Choose your interests</legend>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="model" class="country" name="interest" value="model">
      <label for="model">model</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="Hostess" class="country" name="interest" value="Hostess">
      <label for="hostess">Hostess</label>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button type="submit">Submit form</button>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: If you're trying to remove an item from an array in Javascript, I suggest you look at [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: Using splice in combination with `.indexOf` will let you find the index of an item and remove it.

Comment: Don't "remove" anything, rebuild from a blank array each time, using the selected checkboxes.

Comment: @freedomn-m: can you explain how ? so i can check at my end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you can rebuild the array each time.

Assuming you want a 1-dimensional array rather than an array of arrays, you can use

```
myarray.push(...modelarray);
```

to add the array items.

I've used a `switch` here to match the checkbox value with the array variable, but a better solution for this part (already provided in another answer) is to use an object and get the array by key.  I've kept this with the `switch` to show the difference and use of `.push(...array)`

```js
var myarray = [];
var modelarray = ["A", "B", "C"];
var hostessarray = ["X", "Y"];

$("input:checkbox.country").click(function() {

  // rebuild myarray
  myarray = [];
  $("input:checkbox.country:checked").each(function() {
      switch ($(this).val())
      {
       case "model":
           myarray.push(...modelarray);
           break;
       case "hostess":
           myarray.push(...hostessarray);
           break;
      }
  });
  
  console.log('Updated array is ', myarray);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Choose your interests</legend>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="model" class="country" name="interest" value="model">
      <label for="model">model</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="hostess" class="country" name="interest" value="hostess">
      <label for="hostess">hostess</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit">Submit form</button>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Also in fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cwbvqmp4/

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the array from the checked boxes each time

I suggest an object, where you can get the values based on key

I renamed the class (country) - it does not match the actual values (attributes based on interest)

```js
let myArray;
let interests = {
  "model": ["Height", "size", "bust"],
  "hostess": ["Height", "bust"]
}

$("input:checkbox.interest").on("click", function() {
  myArray = $("input:checkbox.interest:checked")
    .map(function() { console.log(this.value,interests[this.value])
      return interests[this.value]
    }) // get checked boxes and their interests
    .get() // return an array
    .filter(val => val); // remove empty slots
  console.log('Final array is ', myArray);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Choose your interests</legend>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="model" class="interest" name="interest" value="model">
      <label for="model">model</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="Hostess" class="interest" name="interest" value="hostess">
      <label for="hostess">Hostess</label>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button type="submit">Submit form</button>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditions like below while you have static array for both checkboxes.

```js
var myarray = [];
var model = ["Height", "size", "bust"];
var Hostess = ["Height", "bust"];

$("input:checkbox.country").click(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
    if(value === "model"){
      if (!$(this).is(":checked")){
        myarray.splice(myarray.indexOf(model), 1);
      } 
      else{
        myarray.push(model);
      }
    }
    else if(value === "Hostess"){
      if (!$(this).is(":checked")){
        myarray.splice(myarray.indexOf(Hostess), 1);
      } 
      else{
        myarray.push(Hostess);
      }
    }
  console.log('Final array is ', myarray);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Choose your interests</legend>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="model" class="country" name="interest" value="model">
      <label for="model">model</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="Hostess" class="country" name="interest" value="Hostess">
      <label for="hostess">Hostess</label>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button type="submit">Submit form</button>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```